# Bluetooth LE Peripheral Support for Samsung S8

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

I am working with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) using iPhone 8 as central.

Here are few observation on throughput that we found during our RnD on iPhone with BLE. The below data is based on write_with_response.

1. iPhone 8 (BLE 5.0) as Central and Linux desktop (Ubuntu 16.04 with BLE dongle 4.0): MTU = 2048 : Throughput - **2.5 KiloBytes per sec.**
2. iPhone 8 (BLE 5.0) as Central and Android OS with BLE version 4.2 as Peripheral(Xiomi Mi A1): MTU = 180 : Throughput - **2.5 KiloBytes per sec.**
3. iPhone 8 (BLE 5.0) as Central and iPhone 7 plus (BLE 4.2) as Peripheral : MTU = 512 : Throughput - **7.1 KiloBytes per sec.**
4. iPhone 8 (BLE 5.0) as Central and Samsung S8 (BLE 5.0) as Peripheral : **Samsung S8 failed to work as peripheral**
5. iPhone 8 (BLE 5.0) as Central and iPhone 8 plus (BLE 5.0) as Peripheral : MTU = 512 : Throughput - **15.5 KiloBytes per sec.**

As you can see, as the MTU value increases, we get maximum throughput. But we cannot increase to any limit. The above MTU values are the default maximum allowed MTU value as per the given configuration. [MTU - Maximum Transmission Unit. i.e maximum bytes that can be sent in one write request]

I tried connecting iPhone 8 with Samsung S8 using BLE, to check the throughput for Bluetooth LE 5.0 in S8. Here, iPhone 8 is acting as central application and Samsung S8 as BLE Peripheral. I developed custom BLE peripheral application which enables peripheral mode for Samsung S8.

I could able to successfully list Samsung S8 peripheral in my iPhone 8, but I could not able to discover services or characteristics in S8. I also tried with Lightblue app downloaded from app store, but this app also failed to discover services/characteristics in S8. Peripheral mode is working fine with Xiaomi MiA1, which is native Android.

I could able to list and connect to S8 using iPhone 8 via BLE, but on discovering services, S8 is not responding!

So, my question is, is it because of customised Android version of Samsung, in S8 the services are not discoverable to other central application in Peripheral mode? Does Samsung has disabled this feature in S8? Any help is much appreciated.